# App, Uri is null and because that my cursor is also null

Tags: java, android

The uri nul, i don't know why... Please help

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();


    Intent action = new Intent(this, AddReminderActivity.class);
    action.setData(uri);
    PendingIntent operation = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    if (uri != null) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "+OOOOOOOOONUMERO Uriiiii NuLL");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your uri is null because the intent doesn't contain any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uri might be present in `getExtras()` not in `getData()`

So you should use it like below:-

```
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

You can print the extras and see what KEY you should be used to fetch the uri. The following lines of code will print the entire content if a intent extras.

Find out key from the logs and use it.

```
Log.d("intent URI", intent.toUri(0));
```

And finally you can get use it like this:-

```
Uri uri = (Uri) extras.get(KEY);
```

Comment: Could you please accept as answer, so it will help others as well